# Perl script gives a syntax error with Perl v5.20 but not with v5.10

Tags: perl

I have a program which has been working well for quite some time using Perl version 5.10.1.

I now need to run it on version 5.20.2 because it is what is available, and I need a 64-bit environment.

The problem is that under Perl v5.20 this line fails

```
process_command_line("dummy");
```

with this error

```
line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `"dummy"'  
line 16: `process_command_line("dummy");'
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What you have shown is not a syntax error, what is the surrounding code?

Comment: Your code doesn't generate a syntax error in any version of Perl. Furthermore, the error "syntax error near unexpected token" is not a Perl error message. So I expect there's something you're not telling us about how this code is run.

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking the `perl` interpreter? This looks like you are running it against the `bash` interpreter.

Comment: `perl -c -e 'process_command_line("dummy")'` results in `syntax OK`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That is what I`m getting. As I said I don`t understand perl well. The problem might be because I`m running through another script. I`ll try to figure it out

Answer (score 4):

You are executing your Perl script using `sh` (or similar) instead of `perl`. Use `perl` to execute your Perl script.

```
$ cat a.pl
process_command_line("dummy");

$ sh a.pl
a.pl: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"dummy"'
a.pl: line 1: `process_command_line("dummy");'

$ perl a.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::process_command_line called at a.pl line 1.
```